# C# Forward AppointmentItem in Outlook AddIn

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin

I'm trying to programmatically forward an AppointmentItem from within an Outlook Addin. I've retrieved the appointment:

```
var appointment = OutlookApp.ActiveInspector()?.CurrentItem as AppointmentItem
```

I understand that the AppointmentItem does not have a 'Forward' method on it, the MeetingItem does. How can I get the associated MeetingItem from the AppointmentItem so I can forward it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AppointmentItem.ForwardAsVcal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.forwardasvcal) method which forwards the `AppointmentItem` as a `vCal` (virtual calendar item). A `MailItem` object that represents the new mail item to which the calendar information is attached is returned back.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but this wasn't quite the solution I was looking for. I am trying to forward it as if the user clicked on 'Forward'. Attaching it as a Vcal item is not desirable.

Comment: What is your goal by forwarding appointment items? Isn't it better to make a meeting and add an attendee?

Comment: In our Outlook plugin, the user can take action on a meeting - in this case, we want to automatically forward it to a special mailbox. I can create a new meeting with the same attendees, but this new meeting shows up on the user's calendar as a duplicate because they are the organizer for the new meeting.